# How to make Django load profile image files form "media" directory

Tags: django

I have a directory '/media/profile_image' where profile images uploaded by users are saved. In the template I built the url by using the user object

```
<img id="profile_image" src="{{ request.user.profile_image.url }}"></div>
```

```
# Model

def get_profile_image_filepath(self, filename):
    return f'profile_image/{self.pk}/{"profile_image.png"}'

...
    profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image())
...
```

which creates the correct url to the desired directory. But it doesn't show the image, why's that?

```
# rendered url
<img id="profile_image" src="/media/profile_image/1/profile_image.png">
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

dir
[image]

Comment: If `DEBUG = False`, Django does *not* serve static/media files.

Comment: Debug is True though

Comment: did you add the media/static url patterns to the root `urls.py`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no... thanks! Can be closed or Ill delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dealing with Django and media files on development like this :**

1. **First install pillow**
   `pip install pillow` on your activated env.
2. **Specify the MEDIA_ROOT variable in the settings file**
   `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')` or `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'` in `Django 3`.
3. **Tell Django to serve media file (in development mode)**
   `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in the project `urls.py`
   file.
4. **(Optional) Specify the MEDIA_URL variable too**
   URL that handles the media served from `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Exemple :

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media' # or os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/') in Django 2
```

And in your model, you can define a media file like this :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # Others fields
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/")
```

Here the `upload_to` is used to designate the location where the images assigned to the photo attribute will be saved on the hard drive for all instances of the model. If you don't specify a value for `upload_to`, the images will be saved to the root of `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: all done, doesnt show up. I added some stuff to my initial post

Comment: `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` add this line to the project `urls.py` file.